# Is Regex smart enough to take the shortest path (if available) to find a match?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using some "char by char evaluation" to help Regex find the shortest path to a match for a parsing algorithm, but I wonder if the C# Regex engine already does that and I'm just adding unnecessary code.

Currently I first find the next occurrence of the equals sign `=` and then run a regex expression with an offset to capture the name of the key.

Will a regex expression like `([0-9A-Za-z]+\s*)=` try to find first the equals sign? or will it run that expression verbatim and find first a 0-9A-Za-z char THEN check for a whitespace THEN check for an equals sign?

Comment: "How regex engines work" is a bit too broad for SO (you can get some starting points to read at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/122440/how-do-regular-expressions-actually-work). And without actually seeing [MCVE] of "some "char by char evaluation"" it is very hard to see if that is better or worse than regex (if one would base idea of code quality on the user's name I'd bet regex would outperform Dumb Code at least 10x).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The code Im using is so simple I didnt think I would need to include an example of it, I just get the index of char '=' using IndexOf() and then run from there the regex expression that I did include minus the = sign at the end.

Comment: regex in C# properly the same behavior with other regex. regex.Match can find all the matched sections and iterated through .NextMatch().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a trial on [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b0-9A-Za-z%5d%2b%5cs*%29%3d) suggests, regex will look for the group first.
blank search for equal sign costs less, insert a long example text, can´t use a url shortener in so.

Maybe you could use a positive lookbehind, if it fits your requirements.
`(?<=[0-9A-Za-z]+\s*)=`
seems to be faster, like search first for the equal sign.

Comment: Yep, lookbehind seems to be exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Most regular expression engines are greedy and try to match as much as possible. For example, if your input is "hello world on stack overflow", then `[a-z]+\s` will match till the beginning of "overflow" i.e., "hello world on stack ".

The opposite of greedy is [lazy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions). If you use input "hello world on stack overflow" as input and `[a-z]+?\s`, it will match only "hello ".

That said, a regex always starts from left to right, until it has to backtrack. That is, in your example, it will look first for a letter or digit, then keep looking for letters and digits following that first one, then for some spaces, and eventually an equals sign.